# How can Google Chrome isolate tabs into separate processes while looking like a single application?

Tags: architecture, browser, google-chrome, multiprocess

We have been told that Google Chrome runs each tab in a separate process. Therefore a crash in one tab would not cause problems in the other tabs.

AFAIK, multi-processes are mostly used in programs without a GUI.  I have never read any technique that could embed multiple GUI processes into a single one.

How does Chrome do that?

I am asking this question because I am designing CCTV software which will use video decoding SDKs from multiple camera manufactures, some of which are far from stable. So I prefer to run these SDKs in different processes, which I thought is similar to Chrome.

Comment: Download the source and see ! This would be of great benefit to you if you need a similar solution.
Google Chrome is open source.

Comment: My checkout of the Chromium source is 19.7 GB and 545,764 Files. The [links highlighted above](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models) will be a lot faster to go through!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Basically, they use another process that glues them all together into the GUI.

Google Chrome creates three different types of processes: browser, renderers, and plug-ins.

**Browser:**  There's only one browser process, which manages the tabs, windows, and "chrome" of the browser.  This process also handles all interactions with the disk, network, user input, and display, but it makes no attempt to parse or render any content from the web.

**Renderers:**  The browser process creates many renderer processes, each responsible for rendering web pages.  The renderer processes contain all the complex logic for handling HTML, JavaScript, CSS, images, and so on.  Chrome achieves this using the open source WebKit rendering engine, which is also used by Apple's Safari web browser.  Each renderer process is run in a sandbox, which means it has almost no direct access to the disk, network, or display.  All interactions with web apps, including user input events and screen painting, must go through the browser process.  This lets the browser process monitor the renderers for suspicious activity, killing them if it suspects an exploit has occurred.

**Plug-ins:**  The browser process also creates one process for each type of plug-in that is in use, such as Flash, Quicktime, or Adobe Reader.  These processes just contain the plug-ins themselves, along with some glue code to let them interact with the browser and renderers.

Source: [Chromium Blog: Multi-process Architecture](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html)

Comment: I don't get it.  It looks like these tabs belongs to the Browser process, how could these renders draw pictures and text on a tab belongs to another process?

Comment: They don't belong to the Browser process. The Browser process simply manages them (it creates them, stops them, and monitors them). The Browser process also creates the browser GUI, but the internal logic of the tabs (the risky part that is vulnerable to crashes), is handled by the separate Renderer processes (one for each tab).

Comment: Great summary! One thing to add, each Chrome Extension runs in their own process. If you want to know how processes talk to each other, take a look at IPC section in the Chromium source base.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I can see how the HTML, CSS, image etc renderers might somehow serialize the drawing information over to the browser process so it can paint it in the right window. But one cannot say the same for graphics output from plug-ins. Wonder if they are simply having the plugins render to an off-screen surface and then blitting it over to the browser window - but then that seems like it'll be way too slow. And video playback wouldn't be too great as well. Maybe we'll need to look at the source!

Comment: It doesn't quite answer the question of how the rendering works. Does the render process draw on the screen? if so, how does it sync with the 'chrome' part of the screen, which is rendered separately? Does the render process pass image data over RPC for the Browser process to actually draw? That seems like it would be very slow. It seems odd if you have tabs etc. rendered by one process, and 'content' rendered by another.

Answer (score 19):

In this context, the fundamental design is interesting.

Here are the relevant [design documents](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents), in particular the [multi-process architecture](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) section.

An architectural overview:

[image: Architectural overview of browser threads]

Comment: _An image is more than thousand words!_ Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I just gave the first answer (the one explaining 'browser' vs 'renderers' vs 'plugins'
an uptick...that seems the most complete and makes good sense to me.

The only thing I'll add are just a few comments more about WHY Google's design
is the way it is, and give an opinion about why it's always been my first choice
for an overall/every-day browser.  (Tho I realize that HOW (and not WHY) was 
the question being asked.)

Designing so that individual components have their code in separate processes allows 
the OS to'memory-protect' processes from accidently (or on purpose) modifying each 
other in ways not explicitly designed-in.

The only parts in such a design that can both read and write shared data are those
parts that are designed to NEED to access that data, and allows control on whether
that access is just 'read' access or 'read' and 'write' access, etc.  And, since
those access controls are implemented in the hardware, they are firm guarantees
that the access rules cannot be violated.  Thus, plugins and extensions
from other authors and companies, running in separate tabs/processes, cannot
break each other.

Such a design has the effect that it minimises the chances of changing
some code or data that wasn't designed to be changed.  This is for security
reasons and makes for more reliable, less buggy code.

The mere fact Google has such an intricate design is, to me, good testimony to
fact that Google seems to have an excellent grasp of these concepts and has
built a superior product.  (That said, as a web-developer, we still must test
our web code with multiple browsers.  And, browsers such as Firefox, having
been around for a long time and having an excellent group of web-developer related
'add-ons' still has some advantages for some tasks.)

But, for everyday overall browser use, for almost all tasks, the Chrome browser
has become my first choice.  **(Just my opinion, and of course, YMMV.)**

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work of rendering a web page is figuring out where exactly things go (i.e. where to place each picture, what color to render each piece of text). That work is done in a separate process. Once the separate process has figured where everything goes, it passes that information on to the main Chrome process which draws all of the elements on the screen.

It isn't clear exactly how your video sdk system is setup. But you could have one process that decompresses the video and another process that renders it to the display. Most likely however, you are using opengl or DirectX. Those APIs smay impose some limitations on how you split things up among different processes.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, I realize that Chrome is not doing this, but the technique is not dissimilar to OLE.  You have Word document have an embedded Excel Document.  You launch Excel by right-clicking on the spreadsheet in Word and selecting Open.  Excel process is launched to edit the document in a separate process.  Now, if you type something in Excel, you'll see it change on the Word side in real-time.  The way this works is that there's an Excel specific renderer running inside of Word which talks inter-process (using COM IDataObject) to get to the data to draw.

Comment: OLE is a remote procedure call (RPC) architecture. RPC is indeed one way for two process to communicate with each other on the same machine (however it has fallen a out of favor in the past few years).

Answer (score 0):

I came across an article, which I think can answer this question:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome/

Basically, the underlying techniques are IPC and shared memory. There are two rendering models: GPU accelerated and software rendering.

### GPU accelerated

[image]

> The client (code running in the Renderer or within a NaCl module),
> instead of issuing calls directly to the system APIs, serializes them and
> puts them in a ring buffer (the command buffer) residing in memory shared
> between itself and the server process.

> The server (GPU process running in a less restrictive sandbox that
> allows access to the platform's 3D APIs) picks up the serialized commands
> from shared memory, parses them and executes the appropriate graphics
> calls.

### software rendering

[image]

> It is the old software rendering model in which the Renderer process passes (via IPC and shared memory) a bitmap with the page's contents over to the Browser process for display.

Answer (score -2):

Window objects - the small, drawable rectangular areas used to implement widgets, not what the user sees as a window - can perfectly be shared between processes, using shared memory or the X protocol. Check your toolkit's docs.

Comment: each HWND belongs to a particular process

Comment: @zuma that doesn't contradict what I wrote.