# Does all Firefox network traffic go through the parent process

Tags: firefox

In the latest (multiprocess) Firefox (Electrolysis e10s) does *all* network traffic ultimately go through the parent process or do tab (`<browser>` element) processes communicate directly with the outside world eg if using a client websocket connection in the tab's javascript ?

There's a clear picture of what goes on in chrome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028290/4779501) but I haven't managed to find anything similar on Firefox. (I've had a look on MDN under [Multiprocess Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) but can't see the answer).

Please don't respond with "I think" or "its likely" or "try this link" answers - I'm looking for a definitive yes/no and/or relevant link from someone who has found the relevant documentation or possibly worked with the Firefox source code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say something about "all" network traffic in a system as complicated as Firefox.

WebSockets [were remoted a long time ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537787), and on Linux at least the networking in the web content process is [usually disabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1430949), indicating that common web features work by having the central process do the networking.

On Linux, which is what I researched, there are cases when the content process makes network calls: [a remote X11 connection](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1129492) or [third-party apps that load themselves into Firefox processes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1445003). I couldn't easily determine the sandboxing status on Windows; macOS [seems to have networking blocked as well in the content process](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox#OSX).